# How to generate Apple Development identity without Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I need to distribute one unsigned app for Mac OS with arm64 arch.And I want users to automatically sign the application with ad-hoc certificate like this `codesign -s ###### app`.But these users are not developers, and have no Xcode installed.
Is it possible to create Apple Development identity (`########## "Apple Development:mail@mail.com (########)`) using Apple ID and password without Xcode tools?
I know the app Sideloadly is able to do this, but it is closed-source and I'm too stupid to interpret function with disassembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the next command:

```
codesign -fs- name.app -deep
```

But before don't forget to install Xcode command-line tools:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```